# Editing complete FAQ after graduation

Tags: feature-request, site-faq

If a site I moderate has graduated from beta, will I be able to edit all sections of the FAQ ?

Context: I'm a moderator on cstheory, and we just graduated from beta (yippee!). We have a fairly extensive topic-specific FAQ, and right now the only way to get to it is to click on the main FAQ link at the top of the page, and notice the small link in the prefix (that's editable by us). I'd rather just replace the current FAQ by our FAQ, and have the general 'how to use stackoverflow' questions be in a separate link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If a site I moderate has graduated
>   from beta, will I be able to edit all
>   sections of the FAQ ?

No, but seeing as you marked this question as a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), I guess it's rhetorical.

Anyway, the standard SE FAQ is needed—without it, many people assume that SE is just a traditional forum, and SE is different enough from a forum that every person who bothers reading the FAQ counts.

That said, you do have a small area of the FAQ that is editable. Feel free to link that space like there's no tomorrow—see what [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq/) did!

Also, as a side note, I see the CS FAQ is all in one post. The SE policy is to create a separate question for each question, and tag them all [faq](/questions/tagged/faq). This allows better community collaboration when deciding site policies.

Comment: I've got news for you; *with* the FAQ, many people *still* assume that it's a traditional forum.

Comment: @Aarobot I know, but I'm an optimist, and I'm hoping that at least a few people read the FAQ.